# Disallow safe mode on launch for Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, safe-mode

I'm trying to launch into a website using a Selenium MWE:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

However, it's not working. The process itself hangs until it times out.

I think that the problem is that instead of just launching normally whenever Selenium triggers Firefox it triggers it in safe mode:

[image]

Is there a way to disable that behavior?

Comment: What if you would launch firefox manually? Does it start in troubleshoot mode as well?

Comment: Interesting, what are the firefox and selenium versions you have? Thanks.

Comment: `selenium.__version__` says 2.53.5; my Firefox is `Firefox 47`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox 47 and selenium 2.53 don't play nicely together - there are *compatibility issues*:

- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2110
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2257

As a temporary workaround, **downgrade to [Firefox 46](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/)**.

---

Note that the fix into Firefox 47 was already made but not yet released. Which means that you can install the development version of Firefox as well.